# Do any sites offer historical valuation statistics?

Tags: investing, stocks, stock-valuation, historical-analysis

I am new to investing and just learning the basics such as fundamental analysis. One thing I am interested in is retrieving **historical** figures such as P/E, PEG, EPS, etc. Does anyone know where this can be done? For instance I would want to take some ticker and be able to look up what its P/E or PEG ratio was at time X.

I use Fidelity currently, and they don't offer this is a far as I know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out ycharts.com, here is an example of GS

http://ycharts.com/companies/GS

Comment: Some of the ratios are pro-only, but most appear to be free, nice find.